# EventBridge -> AppSync. How to stringify nested json?

Tags: json, aws-appsync, aws-event-bridge

My team decided to use EventBridge and AppSync to implement certain use case.

One part of the AppSync schema uses [AWSJSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html), which is but a string containing any valid json.

Ideally, events sent in the bus are not JSON containing strings with embedded JSON.

In other words, I rather send:

```json
{"outer":{"inner":"foobar"}}
```

than:

```json
 {"outer":"{\"inner\":\"foobar\"}"}
```

However, when configuring the [input transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html#eb-transform-input-api) (the one that transforms an event to an AppSync Graphql request), doesn't seem to be able to stringify nested elements...

I think it's just impossible, but yet, I still make the question. Is it impossible?

Comment: I just do inner = $.outer.inner and reassign to {"outer": {"inner": "<inner>" }}